# How to use exported script from Badboy in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, badboy

Recorded my case in Badboy and exported to jmeter which is saved in desktop. Now how to use this script in jmeter ?

Answer (score 2):

Run `JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.bat` and use `File> Open` the JMX script recorded via Badboy.

It works!

Comment: of note, use this same process to open files created by JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

Like joseK said, you just have to open it via your File/Open Menu in jmeter ...

Or you mean that you've opend it and its not working, in that case you might have some change to do in your exported jmeter test.

Here some problem I got using badboy :

on our apps, badboy seem to add get request that didn't work at all, We had to remove them manually in order to fix the problem.

And if you have a token or session id that you need to extract from your cookies or http response, it's doesn't take care of it for you so you got to figure out how to extract them with a reg-ex extrator and put in a variable that your test will use.

Answer (score 0):

See this link - could be a compatibility problem, if you are running jmeter 2.4 (badboy exports do not work with 2.4 yet). You might have to download 2.3.4 in order to convert the badboy script into a version compatible with 2.4

http://www.pukkared.com/2011/06/using-badboy-to-build-jmeter-test-plans-over-an-ssl/